# NSTimer UIDatePicker dealing with only time

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimer, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

In an iOS app I have a view with a `UIDatePicker` which only selects time (hour, minute, and am/pm). Then based upon the time of the UIDatePicker, sets an `NSTimer`. This timer is supposed to launch daily at the time specified on the `UIDatePicker`. Is there anyway to set up an NSTimer with a specified hour, minute, then either am or pm without having to take the date into consideration? Being able to do this would allow me to remove a huge amount of conditional statements regarding month's, day's and years.

If this isn't possible is there a recommended approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out UILocalNotification:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/